# ¿Cómo ejecutar una línea de comando en CMD después de determinados segundos?

Tags: cmd

Yo estoy ejecutando el comando taskkill con el que cierro un programa.
Lo que quisiera es que el comando no lo cierre al instante, sino que pasen unos determinados segundos y recién lo cierre. ¿Se puede hacer eso en CMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un 'delay' o retraso antes de ejecutar el taskkill.

Para hacer un 'delay' puedes utilizar el comando `timeout (time)` o `timeout /T (time)`. Donde `(time)` es el tiempo de espera antes de seguir con el siguiente comando.

El único incoveniente es que `timeout` genera un texto por defecto con la cantidad de tiempo antes de seguir:

`Waiting for 10 seconds, press a key to continue...`

Si quieres ocultar esto, simplemente añade `> nul` al final del comando. Quedaría así:

`timeout /T 5 > nul`

o bien

`timeout 5 > nul`

Comment: Exelente, ya lo probé! Es ideal este comando! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos, Sunny.

Si estas lanzando el comando y quieres que espere un poco, una opción, poco elegante, es concatenar el comando `taskkill` con un comando que provoque un delay sin afectar.

Un ejemplo podría ser

```
taskkill /pid 1230 && ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
```

Answer (score -1):

También puedes usar `schtask o at` (en desuso), además del `timeout /t * /nobreak`